# Why my compiled kernel is so huge?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I compiled kernel with instructions from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) and ended up with a kernel size of 265M. What did I do wrong? Even the initrd image is 50M.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you have not slipped a digit. Why not post the contents of

`ls -lh /boot`

My guess is that you have compiled a monolithic kernel and not used modules at all if the size is right.

Comment: oh god I'm stupid, I was looking at the .deb package which contained all the modules.

Comment: BTW James, `ls -lh` would be better for ls's that support it...

Comment: I have edited that dmckee